# Do we know if mares outnumber the stallions in Ponyville?

Tags: my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony

From what I've seen in the *My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic* cartoons it seems like there are many more mares than stallions. I'm not talking about speaking roles exclusively. It seems in general, even in pure background characters, there are usually more mares than stallions in a scene. Is the ratio of mares to stallions skewed towards mares in the My Little Pony universe or is it relatively balanced?

One in universe reason I thought of is since the Mane Six are all mares they might naturally pal around with more mares than stallions. This would explain a disparity in speaking roles but not pure background roles. Another thing I thought of out of universe is the target demographic is ostensibly little girls. Perhaps there is a conscious decision by the animators to show more mares roles for that reason.

Is there a known answer to this question? I'd prefer an in universe explanation, but I'm open to a frame challenge showing even splits of mare/stallion characters, or an out of universe answer if it is never addressed in universe.

---

I did scan [this forum post](https://mlpforums.com/topic/65016-the-marestallion-gender-ratio/) but it seemed like mostly fan speculation with the exception of the [info graphic](https://mlpforums.com/uploads/post_images/img-1602766-1-gender_and_race_in_my_little_pony_by_anarchemitis-d4xnzwt.png). I don't know if those ratios hold to the latest season. I don't know if including non-speaking/named ponies would skew things either.

Comment: Wild horses generally have more mates than stallions as the stallion of the heard drives array other stallions. ... maybe something similar?

Answer (score 1):

According to the show's supervising director Jayson Thiessen, there was a concerted attempt to even up the number of mares to stallions in FiM (while at the same time defending the fact that they probably weren't totally successful).

> Q. What's up with the gender ratio in MLP?
>
> A. There are a lot more boy ponies on this show than previous versions of MLP. I'd say it's pretty balanced comparatively... remember it's intended for young GIRLS.
>
> <sub><sup>[Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/mylittlepony/comments/jwp94/im_jayson_thiessen_supervising_director_of_mlpfim/?sort=qa)</sup></sub>

I've seen some comparative sampling that suggests that if you include background non-speaking characters, that by the end of season 2 it's not actually that uneven (approx. 60/40 split)